# LIKE query in Google Cloud datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have my entity in Cloud datastore. One of the properties is Localities, which is concatenated string, eg. 
Los Angeles; San Francisco; Las Vegas. 
Now how do I get data which the below like query will give:

Select * from CloudEntity where Localities like "%San Francisco%"

Answer (score 4):

Instead of storing a single string, store a list of strings. Then use an equality filter. In json it would be:

```
Localities:  {listValue: [
    {stringValue: "Los Angeles"}, 
    {stringValue: "San Francisco"}, 
    {stringValue: "Las Vegas"}]}
```

then:

```
Select * from CloudEntity where Localities = "San Francisco"
```